# SQL Server 2005 Partition table by foreign referenced data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, partitioning

is there a canonical way to partition a table by referenced data to another table?

for example

```
timetable
   id
   datetime

bigtable
   id
   timetable_id -- foreign key
   .. other data ..
```

i want to partition bigtable by the datetime in timetable.  thankx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic19), he partitioning column must be a part of all unique indexes on the table, which would include your primary key.

I think your only choice here would be to denormalize the `timetable.datetime` column into `bigtable` so that the column is available for partitioning.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning key **must** be a column of the table being partitioned. If you have a correlation between `id` and `datetime` in `timetable` then you can partition by that id:

```
id          datetime
1           20091001
2           20091002
3           20091003
...
32          20091101
33          20091102
...
62          20091201
...
```

then the partitioning ranges (2009-10-01, 2009-10-31), (2009-11-01, 2009-11-30) etc can be expressed in terms of `id` values: (1,31), (32,62), ... However, this requires that the rank of the `id` values matches exactly the rank of the `datetime` values. If you don't have this correlation, then you must either move the `datetime` column in the `bigtable`, or rearrange your `id` so that they correlate wqitht he `datetime`.

Comment: unfortunately id is a uniqueidentifier, so it wont have that property